# Making Sure Nodes are visible

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

So I have this sprite kit game, which is coded in swift 2. The game includes these colored circles (Green, Red, Purple, Yellow, Blue) that fall down the screen, starting from the same height, but starting at different widths. When the circles hit the bottom of the screen, the respectable method is called. The problem I am having is, the random x position can sometimes cut half of the circle off because it is on the very side of the screen. How can I prevent the circles from clipping the side of the screen? Here are the methods that are called when the circles hit the bottom of the screen.

```
    func changeGreen(){

    Green.position.y = frame.size.height * 0.9

    let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))

    Green.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

}

func changeRed(){

    Red.position.y = frame.size.height * 0.9

    let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))

    Red.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

}

func changeBlue()   {

    Blue.position.y = frame.size.height * 0.9

    let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))

    Blue.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

}

func changeYellow() {

    Yellow.position.y = frame.size.height * 0.9

    let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))

    Yellow.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

}

func changePurple() {

    Purple.position.y = frame.size.height * 0.9

    let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))

    Purple.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming position.x is the center of the circle, I think something like this might work:

```
let maxX = 350    // this is your frame width
let radius = 50   // radius of the circle
var positionX = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxX - radius))) // max position of x is taken care of here


let pointsFromLeft = positionX - radius
if pointsFromLeft < 0 {
    positionX -=  pointsFromLeft // move to the right if necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to offset the `radius` of the circle from both ends of `frame` so that the circles never get clipped.

```
let radius = 20 // radius of your circle
let positionX = radius + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2 * radius))
```

Comment: Your solution also works. I had a problem with the game scene width and height being different than the screen width and height, but I resolved that.